# Remap LeftAlt+J to ArrowDown

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg

On a bare bones Linux installation (using `xkb` / `xmodmap`) is it possible to remap the `LeftAlt+J` to send a `ArrowDown`? I have found all sort of workarounds or slightly different scenarios with `CapsLock+J` and so on but none using exactly `LeftAlt+J`.

Ideally this should work without having to change `LeftAlt` for `AltGr` and `LeftAlt` will still keep it's normal behavior. Eg: `LeftAlt+F` still opens the `File` menu in apps that have it.

Also, I mentioned `xkb` and `xmodmap` because I would like this to work everywhere instead of just remaps in certain apps.

One of the minimum requirements for this to be an accepted solution is, one should be able to open Firefox, focus the address bar, type something and with `LeftAlt+J` to navigate down the suggestions.

In my tests tools like `xdotool` and `xte` didn't work well, but I'm happy to be corrected.

System: Linux with BSPWM, so no Gnome or KDE workarounds.

PS: I'm not looking for a spoon-fed solution but if someone can point me in the right direction, I will do the rest myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(This answer has not been tested, but you implied that this is fine.)

The
[Keymap table](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Keymap_table)
that is printed by the command `xmodmap -pke` includes several columns,
of which the first 4 stand for the combinations of:

1. Key
2. Shift+Key
3. Mode_switch+Key
4. Mode_switch+Shift+Key

I don't know what "Mode_switch" stands for, but it could be assigned as LeftAlt
by the command:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_L = Mode_switch"
```

This means that the third entry above stands now for the combination
of the key with LeftAlt.

The keycode for `j` seems to be 44. Its entry in the `xmodmap` file can be
retrieved by:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep 44
```

Which might return:

```
keycode  44 = j J j J dead_hook dead_horn dead_hook
```

Then modifying it to map <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to
<kbd>Down</kbd> can be done with:

```
keycode  44 = j J Down J dead_hook dead_horn dead_hook
```

To do that, use the command

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J Down J dead_hook dead_horn dead_hook"
```

This answer might need some tweaking, but might work.

---

Alternatively, you could consider using
[AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey):
a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11 (also see the
[wiki](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki)).

AutoKey might already be available as a standard package in your repository.

[image]

Comment: Mode_switch is the the predecessor of AltGr and has similar behavior. Using it in place of AltL will break existing AltL shortcuts (eg. AltL+F)

Comment: You could in that case consider [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey):  a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11 (also see [wiki](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki)). It might be available as a package in your repository.